# Tkinter returning wrong screen dimensions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the screen size in mm in python using Tkinter. However it consistently returns the wrong screen dimensions. Using the following code I obtain 406mm, although the real display is 344.2mm according to the specifications.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

screenWidth = root.winfo_screenmmwidth()

print(screenWidth)

root.destroy()
```

I though it would be a scaling issue (the Windows scale and layout option is set to 125%), but dividing  the size by the scaling factor returns 324.8mm, which is also not the real value. I cannot wrap my head around what is wrong.

When I get the resolution, tkinter also returns wrong values. My display is 1920x1080, but the tkinter returns 1536x864, which is apart from the real value by exactly the windows scaling factor.

Comment: Did you measure the outer dimensions of the screen, or the actual visible area? 344.2 - 324.8 = 19,4 mm sounds like a plausible size for a screen bezel.

Comment: Yes, the actual visible screen size is 340mm when measuring with a ruler. The plastic outline adds an additional 1.4cm around the screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243966/how-can-i-get-the-true-screen-size-in-tkinter